# Split parts of strings into a list column and then make a vector column

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to run a function on every row fulfilling a certain criterium, which returns a data frame - the idea is then to take the list of data frames and rbindlist them together for a totally separate data.table. (I'm extracting several URL links from each forum post, and tagging them with the forum post they came from).

I tried doing this with a data.table

```
getUrls <- function(text, id) {
  matches <- str_match_all(text, url_pattern)
  a <- data.frame(urls=unlist(matches))
  a$id <- id
  a
}

a <- db[has_url == TRUE, getUrls(text)]
```

and get the message

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "id", value = c(1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 4L,  : 
  replacement has 11007 rows, data has 29787
```

Because some rows have several URLs... However, I don't care that these rowlengths don't match, I still want these rows :) I thought J would just let me execute arbitrary R code in the context of the rows as variable names, etc.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for db? By the way, you're missing a `)` in `getUrls(text`. Also, it's considered safer to use TRUE and FALSE (instead of T and F).

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement, see below, feel free to provide more feedback.

Answer (score 3):

We can rewrite this making it much more compact, eschewing the function. We'll do it in two steps, first we'll create a new column which holds a list (data.table columns can hold almost anything, even embedded data.tables), and then we'll extract these into a new data.table.

```
url_pattern <- "http[^([:blank:]|\\\"|<|&|#\n\r)]+"

db[(has_url), urls := str_match_all(text, url_pattern)]
urls <- db[(has_url), list(url=unlist(urls)), by=id]
```

Note that we use (has_url) instead of has_url == T, this uses binary indexing which is much faster (although in this case, most of the time is taken up by str_match_all, so it won't make that much difference). Make sure you use the () though, otherwise it won't work.

The second line creates db$urls, which is a list of urls. The third line generates a new data.table, which has one entry for each URL, with the ID field linking it back to the forum post it came from.

db has 146k rows, db[(has_url),] has 11k rows, and urls has 30k rows (some posts have several urls).

Sample output from head(urls):

```
id  url
14  http://reganmian.net/blog
44  http://vg.no
59  http://koran.co.id
```

**Update, simple reproducible example**

Let's first generate some data

```
texts = c("Stian fruit:apple, fruit:banana and fruit:pear",
          "Peter fruit:apple",
          "fruit:banana is delicious",
          "I don't agree")
DT <- data.table(text = texts, id=1:length(texts))

DT
                                             text id
1: Stian fruit:apple, fruit:banana and fruit:pear  1
2:                              Peter fruit:apple  2
3:                      fruit:banana is delicious  3
4:                                  I don't agree  4
```

We want to grab all the "fruits" from the text column (each row might have one, several or no fruits). We first use str_match_all to put a list of individual fruits into a new column.

```
pattern <- "fruit:\\S*"

DT[, fruit_list := str_match_all(text, pattern)]
```

Now the fruit field looks like this:

```
> DT[1]$fruit_list
[[1]]
     [,1]          
[1,] "fruit:apple,"
[2,] "fruit:banana"
[3,] "fruit:pear"
```

Now we want to extract the fruits into a new table, with one row per fruit, keeping the link back to the ID

```
fruits <- DT[, list(fruit=unlist(fruit_list)), by=id]
```

And the result

```
> fruits
   id        fruit
1:  1 fruit:apple,
2:  1 fruit:banana
3:  1   fruit:pear
4:  2  fruit:apple
5:  3 fruit:banana
```

(thank you to Matthew Dowle and Ricardo Saporta on data.table-help mailing list)

Comment: I feel like examples, and maybe some other parts of this answer belong in the question...?

Comment: This is the first time I've tried to answer my own question... The information in the question now is actually the information I had when I asked it (on the mailing list)... I could try to rejig to make it more pedagogical, but it seems a bit artificial to "author" a question and an answer. I think I'll leave it for now, hopefully it will be a useful reference to some.

Comment: Yeah, I've never answered my own question before, either, but I think the only reason to do it is for pedagogical purposes, right? Anyway, it's fine as-is, too, same as when I saw it on the mailing list :).

Comment: I get an error when I try to use :=  . Where does it come from?